# Why cant my Altcoin Regnet create first 100 blocks?

Tags: altcoin-development, regtest, genesis-block

I have modified bitcoin source code for my altcoin. I have successfully created genesis block, merkel root, noonce and daemon is working well. I have tweaked number of coins per day, total coins etc.. I have also set the bitcoin.conf to server=1, regtest=1 with rpc user and password.

Now i am following the bitcoin CLI tutorial to create first 101 blocks,  but it only creates 1 block instead of 101 blocks.

https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#testing-applications

The problem is using the CLI, when i generate 100 blocks only one block is created why?

Here is my chainparams.cpp (clipped code)

```
/**
 * Regression test
 */
class CRegTestParams : public CChainParams {
public:
    CRegTestParams() {
        strNetworkID = "regtest";
        consensus.nSubsidyHalvingInterval = 150;
        consensus.BIP16Height = 0; // always enforce P2SH BIP16 on regtest
        consensus.BIP34Height = 100000000; // BIP34 has not activated on regtest (far in the future so block v1 are not rejected in tests)
        consensus.BIP34Hash = uint256();
        consensus.BIP65Height = 1351; // BIP65 activated on regtest (Used in rpc activation tests)
        consensus.BIP66Height = 1251; // BIP66 activated on regtest (Used in rpc activation tests)
        consensus.powLimit = uint256S("7fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff");
        consensus.nPowTargetTimespan = 14 * 24 * 60 * 60; // two weeks
        consensus.nPowTargetSpacing = 10 * 60;
        consensus.fPowAllowMinDifficultyBlocks = true;
        consensus.fPowNoRetargeting = true;
        consensus.nRuleChangeActivationThreshold = 108; // 75% for testchains
        consensus.nMinerConfirmationWindow = 144; // Faster than normal for regtest (144 instead of 2016)[/code]
```

and in the commanline, it is executing only one block.

```
./bitcoin-cli -regtest generate 101
[
  "179ef1bb855aed3d01324e6eff17ce63773b3ae79a0e123bfdf7f5d11cad0360"
]
```

and the output (clipped)

```
 ./bitcoin-cli -regtest getblockchaininfo
    {
      "chain": "regtest",
      "blocks": 4,
      "headers": 4,
      "bestblockhash": "179ef1bb855aed3d01324e6eff17ce63773b3ae79a0e123bfdf7f5d11cad0360",
      "difficulty": 4.656542373906925e-10,
      "mediantime": 1516037681,
      "verificationprogress": 1,
      "initialblockdownload": false,
      "chainwork": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100010009",
      "size_on_disk": 1551,
      "pruned": false,
      "softforks": [
        {
          "id": "bip34",
          "version": 2,
          "reject": {
            "status": false
          }
```

What is preventing creating 101 blocks?

I am seeing this in debug.log

```
2018-01-16 20:40:30 Bitcoin version v0.15.99.0-45173fa6f-dirty
2018-01-16 20:40:30 InitParameterInteraction: parameter interaction: -whitelistforcerelay=1 -> setting -whitelistrelay=1
2018-01-16 20:40:30 Assuming ancestors of block 0000000000000000003b9ce759c2a087d52abc4266f8f4ebd6d768b89defa50a have valid signatures.
2018-01-16 20:40:30 Setting nMinimumChainWork=000000000000000000000000000000000000000000723d3581fe1bd55373540a
2018-01-16 20:40:30 Using the 'sse4' SHA256 implementation
2018-01-16 20:40:30 Using RdRand as an additional entropy source
2018-01-16 20:40:30 Default data directory /Users/prabhubalakrishnan/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin
2018-01-16 20:40:30 Using data directory /Users/prabhubalakrishnan/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin
2018-01-16 20:40:30 Using config file /Users/prabhubalakrishnan/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/bitcoin.conf
2018-01-16 20:40:30 Using at most 125 automatic connections (283 file descriptors available)
2018-01-16 20:40:30 Using 16 MiB out of 32/2 requested for signature cache, able to store 524288 elements
2018-01-16 20:40:30 Using 16 MiB out of 32/2 requested for script execution cache, able to store 524288 elements
2018-01-16 20:40:30 Using 4 threads for script verification
2018-01-16 20:40:30 scheduler thread start
2018-01-16 20:40:30 HTTP: creating work queue of depth 16
2018-01-16 20:40:30 Config options rpcuser and rpcpassword will soon be deprecated. Locally-run instances may remove rpcuser to use cookie-based auth, or may be replaced with rpcauth. Please see share/rpcuser for rpcauth auth generation.
2018-01-16 20:40:30 HTTP: starting 4 worker threads
2018-01-16 20:40:30 Using wallet directory /Users/prabhubalakrishnan/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin
2018-01-16 20:40:30 init message: Verifying wallet(s)...
2018-01-16 20:40:30 Using BerkeleyDB version Berkeley DB 4.8.30: (April  9, 2010)
2018-01-16 20:40:30 Using wallet wallet.dat
2018-01-16 20:40:30 CDBEnv::Open: LogDir=/Users/prabhubalakrishnan/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/database ErrorFile=/Users/prabhubalakrishnan/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/db.log
2018-01-16 20:40:30 Cache configuration:
2018-01-16 20:40:30 * Using 2.0MiB for block index database
2018-01-16 20:40:30 * Using 8.0MiB for chain state database
2018-01-16 20:40:30 * Using 440.0MiB for in-memory UTXO set (plus up to 286.1MiB of unused mempool space)
2018-01-16 20:40:30 init message: Loading block index...
2018-01-16 20:40:30 Wiping LevelDB in /Users/prabhubalakrishnan/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/blocks/index
2018-01-16 20:40:30 Opening LevelDB in /Users/prabhubalakrishnan/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/blocks/index
2018-01-16 20:40:30 Opened LevelDB successfully
2018-01-16 20:40:30 Using obfuscation key for /Users/prabhubalakrishnan/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/blocks/index: 0000000000000000
2018-01-16 20:40:30 Initializing databases...
2018-01-16 20:40:30 Wiping LevelDB in /Users/prabhubalakrishnan/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/chainstate
2018-01-16 20:40:30 Opening LevelDB in /Users/prabhubalakrishnan/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/chainstate
2018-01-16 20:40:30 Opened LevelDB successfully
2018-01-16 20:40:30 Wrote new obfuscate key for /Users/prabhubalakrishnan/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/chainstate: 58c6b9c1e6d24649
2018-01-16 20:40:30 Using obfuscation key for /Users/prabhubalakrishnan/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/chainstate: 58c6b9c1e6d24649
2018-01-16 20:40:30  block index              38ms
2018-01-16 20:40:30 init message: Loading wallet...
2018-01-16 20:40:30 nFileVersion = 159900
2018-01-16 20:40:30 Keys: 1002 plaintext, 0 encrypted, 1002 w/ metadata, 1002 total
2018-01-16 20:40:30  wallet                   38ms
2018-01-16 20:40:30 setKeyPool.size() = 1000
2018-01-16 20:40:30 mapWallet.size() = 0
2018-01-16 20:40:30 mapAddressBook.size() = 2
2018-01-16 20:40:30 Reindexing block file blk00000.dat...
2018-01-16 20:40:30 UpdateTip: new best=00000000f81247b7a7fe3c913d1d4ca3e8534349639cf21d0a0ed45fad2582c5 height=0 version=0x00000001 log2_work=32.000022 tx=1 date='2018-01-08 16:25:32' progress=0.000000 cache=0.0MiB(0txo)
2018-01-16 20:40:30 mapBlockIndex.size() = 1
2018-01-16 20:40:30 nBestHeight = 0
2018-01-16 20:40:30 torcontrol thread start
2018-01-16 20:40:30 Bound to [::]:21600
2018-01-16 20:40:30 Bound to 0.0.0.0:21600
2018-01-16 20:40:30 init message: Loading P2P addresses...
2018-01-16 20:40:30 Loaded 1025 addresses from peers.dat  4ms
2018-01-16 20:40:30 init message: Loading banlist...
2018-01-16 20:40:30 init message: Starting network threads...
2018-01-16 20:40:30 net thread start
2018-01-16 20:40:30 dnsseed thread start
2018-01-16 20:40:30 addcon thread start
2018-01-16 20:40:30 init message: Done loading
2018-01-16 20:40:30 opencon thread start
2018-01-16 20:40:30 msghand thread start
2018-01-16 20:40:30 Loaded 1 blocks from external file in 208ms
2018-01-16 20:40:30 Reindexing finished
2018-01-16 20:40:30 Imported mempool transactions from disk: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 expired, 0 already there
2018-01-16 20:40:41 Loading addresses from DNS seeds (could take a while)
2018-01-16 20:40:41 0 addresses found from DNS seeds
2018-01-16 20:40:41 dnsseed thread exit
 2018-01-17 15:45:56 Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 68726 seconds ago)
    2018-01-17 15:56:26 Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 69356 seconds ago)
    2018-01-17 16:06:56 Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 69986 seconds ago)
    2018-01-17 16:17:26 Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 70616 seconds ago)
    2018-01-17 16:27:56 Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 71246 seconds ago)
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of the debug.log file?

Comment: @AndrewChow Posted the debug.log

Comment: The section of debug.log you posted is completely useless. Post all of it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `generate` command is wrong.

try: `./bitcoin-cli -regtest generate 101 -1`

The `-1` part means the daemon will continue attempting to generate blocks indefinitely until the amount of blocks, `101` have been generated